# td positioning within tr

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have a table which has multiple `<td>` elements.

I need the elements to be part of the `<tr>` but a split on 2 lines:

Example:

```
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
```

The goal I want to achieve is that 1,2,3 and 4 are on one line and 5 will be under them but spanning the whole length of the `<tr>`

I do not want to use multiple `<tr>` elements.

I have added no code as I have tried to google but haven't found anything and I have no clue where to start from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To style the table without modifying the markup, you can change the `display` properties of the `tr` and `td` to `block`.

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/124sd9zy/2/)** to see it in action.

The markup:

```
<h3>original table</h3>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h3>larger table</h3>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    color: #222;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
}
table * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
tr {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 0;
}
tr:before, tr:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
}
tr:after {
    clear: both;
}
td {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    border-right: 1px solid #222;
}
td:nth-child(5) {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #222;
}
tr:nth-of-type(1n+2) {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rowspan after your 4th  it will solve your issue!